# ASP.net C# : All User Session Expires when any one user's Session Expires/Flushed

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am running an ASP.NET 4.0(C#) application is Hosted on Shared Server. When multiple people working, Session will be expires without ideal, But when single people working it will never expires even after 15-20 min ideal.

**The worst part is someone logged out(Because of session expires), All Users who using system will logged out.**

I have done the following

```
set in web.config
Set session timeout to 60 minutes in IIS manager/Web site
```

properties/ASP.NET configuration settings
    Set idle timeout to 60 minutes in application pool properties/performance.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="60" />
```

My codes,

Set Value to Session On Login

```
Session["UserId"] = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["UserId"]);
```

Check value of Session of Page Page_PreInit

```
if (Session["UserId"] == null)
{
       Response.Redirect("~/Index.aspx");
}
```

Get Value of Session On Page When Requered

```
string UserId = Convert.ToString(Session["UserId"]);
```

When Multiple People Loggedin and working On Page_PreInit event Session["UserId"] will be Null and redirected to Login Page as per code. But when single person working or using Session will never becomes Null, even after 15 min Ideal.
I don't know what i did wrong?

Comment: put full code when create your session

Comment: Denish, There is nothing like full code. I had made sample application that had web config with above given setting. And i am writing value in Session UserId at login. As you can assume "1" and then in Page Page_PreInit checking Session is Null or not and Just Getting Session value as per above code just for log.

Answer (score 0):

You're using "InProc" for your session state, so your Session object is being saved inside your ASP.NET worker process. When the application pool recycles, your worker process is restarted and the session sate is lost.

Odds are good that when you have multiple users on your site you're hitting some memory/cpu limit that's causing IIS to recycle the worker process. When it's only a single user testing your site, the limits are not reached and the worker process is not recycling.

Try using the "StateServer" mode which uses an external process (service) to store the session. It will survive a recycling of the worker process.

Comment: I tried using *StateServer* but it does not hit *Session_End*, then I can't save the expire Date Time timestamp.